# Segmentation fault (core dumped) error - CodeIgniter application / Ubuntu 14.04 / PHP 5.5

Tags: php, codeigniter, ubuntu-14.04

Strange error within one CI application I am running on my localhost. The error appeared after upgrading PHP to 5.5. The other apps on my localhost are running fine so likely something within the project code. Can anyone suggest what I can configure differently or what might be chucking this error? I have read various other posts regarding the segmentation fault but nothing has applied

The apache log shows the following:

```
    [core:notice] [pid 1696] AH00051: child pid 5390 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
```

results of php version:

```
    $ php -v
    PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.4 (cli) (built: Sep  4 2014 06:56:34) 
    Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
    Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
```

If I run the app from the command line with strace (truncated for readability)

```
    $ strace php index.php
    ....
    mmap(NULL, 14963, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 3, 0) = 0x7f0089e52000
    munmap(0x7f0089e52000, 14963)           = 0
    close(3)                                = 0
    brk(0x1bee000)                          = 0x1bee000
    ....
    brk(0x25ae000)                          = 0x25ae000
    --- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0x7fff07b47ff8} ---
    +++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++
    Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Anyone got any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK waste of time posting this in the end was fairly easy to find. For some reason the following does not make for happy play - I was setting a protected variable of my MY_Model class directly using $this->config->item() and this was causing the issue.

so if I do this:

```
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->protected_var = $this->config->item('config_val','config_file');
    }
```

It freaks out. But if I use a setter function:

```
    $this->setter($val = false){
        if(!empty($val)){
            $this->protected_var = $val;
        }
    }
```

Its fine. Pff!

Answer (score 0):

I found the same problem.

To solve this i config my autoload do load my config file.

In my case i create a config file: mongoci.php

So, in autoload.php i load the config file:

```
$autoload['config'] = array('mongoci');
```

Please try include your config file.